# $C^\infty$ structure subordinate to a $C^k$ structure of a manifold

Tags: manifolds

In Ludwig Arnold's *Random Dynamical Systems*, he says

> On a paracompact manifold $M$ there is a $C^\infty$ structure subordinate to a $C^k$ structure of $M$ for $1\le k<\infty$ (Whitney).

I don't quite understand his meaning (like, what does 'subordinate to' mean?). I only know Whitney Embedding Theorem, but I hardly see any connections. And I didn't find any other Whitney's theorems related it.

Comment: This is literally a theorem of Whitney. It is not related to the embedding theorem. It means that there is a subatlas of your $C^k$ structure for which all the transition functions are smooth.

Comment: @MikeMiller Thanks a lot for your comment. Could I ask where I can find this theorem and its proof? That would be of great help.

Comment: There's a proof in Hirsch's differential topology book.

Comment: @MikeMiller Thanks :)